# Can jenkins run two plugins that extend RtcExtensionProvider?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rational-team-concert

I have two plugins and both are extends RtcExtensionProvider. Let's call plugin A and plugin B.
When only one of those plugin is installed into jenkins server, it run normally.
But if I install both of them, only plugin A is run, plugin B is disable totally.

**So I want to know, can both of them run in one job?**

I tried to change installation order of two plugin, but plugin A is always run, and plugin B is always disabled.
I tried to change name and id of plugin B so that plugin B name place before plugin A name in dictionary, but this isn't help.